# Moq and Transactionscope, can you make the moqs not count?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, transactionscope

When i'm using a Transactionscope that i don't commmit, moq still sees all the rolled back calls to the database.

Is there a way of doing

```
_mockRepository.Verify(x => x.InsertSBI(It.IsAny<Int32>(), It.IsAny<Int32>(), It.IsAny<String>()), Times.Never());
```

And not

```
_mockRepository.Verify(x => x.InsertSBI(It.IsAny<Int32>(), It.IsAny<Int32>(), It.IsAny<String>()), Times.Exactly(4));
```

to make the test succeed?

Comment: Are you mocking out the transaction? If so, then verifying the four calls to the row insertions and then the callback should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple strategies come to mind.

- Create a wrapper class for your existing DB access class.  Make that wrapper wait to forward any calls to the underlying implementation until you call `Commit`.

I don't recommend this.  It would be a pointless abstraction reserved only for test, because the real DB class (probably) does the same thing under the covers.  It will wait to call the DB until `Commit` is called.

- Don't try to validate data access this way.  Instead **validate that `Commit` *wasn't* called**.

What you're trying to do is *stateful* testing - you're validating the *state* of those calls, based on how `Commit` and `Rollback` effect them.  This is not the right way to go about using mocks.

If you validate that `Commit` wasn't called, you're testing the high-level behavior of the code that is rolling back the transaction, and its interaction with the DB class.  You verify that rollback is called, and that commit isn't called, and trust that it will correctly handle the details.

Something like:

```
_mockRepository.Verify(x => x.Commit(), Times.Never());
_mockRepository.Verify(x => x.Rollback(), Times.Once());
```

If you need to verify the DB class itself you can mock out its DB connection and verify that calls don't get made if `Rollback` is invoked.  But you shouldn't do that sort of testing unless you're unit testing that DB class directly.

Comment: +1 for the second suggestion, especially since I imagine most DB classes will be sending all calls to the DB and letting the DB handle rollback and commit (I haven't verified that but I'd be a little bit terrified if that sort of transactional detail wasn't the responsibility of the DB implementation)

Comment: @DavidHall: ORM libraries often implement local change tracking and only round-trip when they have to.  Of course the logic on *when* it would round-trip would be complex, which is why it should be tested on its own instead of when unit testing higher level code (and in integration tests.  Ideally it shouldn't be tested directly at all, as someone else wrote and presumably tested it).

Comment: really? I'll have to read up on that - I've always presumed that they wouldn't. It makes sense I guess, a good ORM will try and help with things like n+1 problems, so why not also transaction managment. Of course, as you say, the key point is that unless you are writing an ORM it should be an implementation detail that you don't need to test directly!